# Change and reinitialized autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery [Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)
I have some code.
I tried to modify "source" autocomplete by select, but when i change source autocomplete don't work. I try use .change, .on, .click for reinitialized but still not working. 
When i use non modified source, autocomplete works fine.

```js
$('#myselect').change(function() {
  $('#part_q').prop("disabled", false).focus();
  var brand = $('#myselect').val();
  $('#part_q').autocomplete({
    source: 'https://example.com/search/?' + brand
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
     <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="">Select Brand</option>
     <option value="1">Some brand</option>
     <option value="2">Some brand 2</option>
     <option value="3">Some brand 3</option>
</select>
<input disabled="" placeholder="Model Name" type="text" id="part_q" name="part_q">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple snippet showing how to achieve autocomplete refresh functionality, please use this code and let me know if there are any issues implementing it for your use case!

```js
var arr = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3][4,4]];
$('#myselect').change(function() {
  $('#part_q').prop("disabled", false).focus();
  var brand = $('#myselect').val();
  $('#part_q').autocomplete("option", { source: arr[brand] });
});

$("#part_q").autocomplete({
  source: []
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="">Select Brand</option>
            <option value="0">Some brand</option>
            <option value="1">Some brand 2</option>
            <option value="2">Some brand 3</option>
            <option value="4">Some brand 4</option>
    </select>
<input disabled="" placeholder="Model Name" type="text" id="part_q" name="part_q">
```

Comment: For me important to save that parameter. "source:'https://example.com/search/?'+brand" because there dynamic value. By the way, in stackoverflow it's working ... when change input, autocomplete working ... wierd. ..

Comment: @AleksandrPetric yes, so use the url instead of the array I used! like `("option", { source: "example.com/search/?"+brand });`

Comment: @AleksandrPetric did this solve your issue completely?